# Web Scraping Java Sites with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Let me start out by saying that I am no pro at web scraping.  I can do the basics on most platforms, but that's about it.

I am trying to create the foundation for a web application that can helps users reinforce their language learning by generating additional data, metrics, as well as create new tools for self-testing.  The Duolingo website is not offering up any sort of API so my next thought *for now* is just to scrape https://www.duome.eu/.  I wrote a quick little scraper but didn't realize that the site was java.  In the following example, it is my wish to collect all of the words from the `Words` tab that contain anchors:

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DuolingoUpdate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userName = "Podus";
            UpdateDuolingoUser(userName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async void UpdateDuolingoUser(string userName)
        {
            string url = "https://www.duome.eu/" + userName + "/progress/";

            // Create the http client connection
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            // Store the html client data in an object
            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

            //var words = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
            //    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("id", "")
            //    .Equals("words")).ToList();

            //var wordList = words[0].Descendants("a")
            //    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
            //    .Contains("wA")).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(html);
        }
    }
}
```

The html object of the above code contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Duolingo · Podus @ duome.eu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css?1548418871" />
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if("".length==0){
            var visitortime = new Date();
            var visitortimezone = "GMT " + -visitortime.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
            //localStorage.tz = visitortimezone;
            //timezone = Date.parse(localStorage.tz);
            //timezone = localStorage.tz;
            //console.log(timezone);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/tz.php",
                data: 'time='+ visitortimezone,
                success: function(){
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<noscript>Click <a href="https://duome.eu//Podus/progress/">here</a> to adjsut XP charts to your local timezone. </noscript>
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter --> <script type="text/javascript" > (function (d, w, c) { (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() { try { w.yaCounter47765476 = new Ya.Metrika({ id:47765476, clickmap:true, trackLinks:true, accurateTrackBounce:true }); } catch(e) { } }); var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0], s = d.createElement("script"), f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); }; s.type = "text/javascript"; s.async = true; s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js"; if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") { d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false); } else { f(); } })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks"); </script> <noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/47765476" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript> <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
</body>
</html>
```

But if you go to the actual url https://www.duome.eu/Podus/progress/, the site contains a ton of script.  So upon inspection the first problem is that I am not getting the html that I see in the browser.  The second problem is that if you view source, its nothing like what is in `inspect` and I don't see anything in source that would lead me to isolate the data from `div id="words"`.

Given my lackluster knowledge of java built web pages, how do I do this, or is it even possible?

Comment: Use [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) instead of HAP.

Comment: The `div id="words"` section does not exist until you click on a label:  `<label for="tabWords">Words</label>`. The `DIV` you're looking for then appears. You can do this using a WebBrowser, Navigate to the address, parse the page, find that Label Element and `InvokeMember("click")` on it, wait for the page to refresh and get the `DIV` by its `ID`.

Comment: @MichaelRandall do you have a recommendation?

Comment: @IanKemp according to the AngleSharp FAQ, they don't seem to support java interaction.  https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/blob/master/doc/Questions.md#is-it-possible-to-get-the-html-after-javascript-and-blazor-run

Comment: This page only returns the full expected html if you pass a valid `Cookie` request header.

Comment: Seems like everyone has different answers >.<

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the response using postman and passing in my own `Cookie` response header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Hzx.png - Unfortunately I haven't been able to replicate this in C# yet

Comment: @rshepp how about python?  Been a minute since I used BS4 but my scraping knowledge skill there is no better anyway :P

Comment: There are no specific answers and everyone has it's tools of choice. What is sure is that page is dinamically generated, almost entirely by scripts (JavaScript, by the way. Nothing to do with Java). You need a tool that can execute scripts to load the full extent of the page(s). A WebBrowser can do that. Easily, that's its job.

Comment: @Jimi the page html is generated server-side, but it seems to have a mechanism to prevent amateur scraping. Nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: @rshepp  Look twice. The code inside the page, I mean.

Comment: @Jimi see the screenshot I posted above. I've produced the final html with postman alone (no javascript).

Comment: @Jimi I really don't understand why you're suggesting I use a web browser.  That defeats the purpose.

Comment: @rshepp  We're looking at two different pages. The address I'm referring to is `https://www.duome.eu/Podus/progress/`.

Comment: A WebBrowser is a tool you use in code, like WebRequest or HttpClient. Like the .Net WinForms/WPF WebBrowser class or GeckoFx etc. Headless Browsers.

Comment: @Jimi it looks to me like he's using the same URL as you...

Comment: Which is the address you're looking for? The `DIV` you're referring to is found in the address I just posted. It looks like the other address is `https://www.duome.eu/`.

Comment: @Jimi `https://www.duome.eu/Podus/progress/` is correct. That is the URL at the top of his postman window.

Comment: OK, then. If the `Words` Tab can be activated with cookies (instead of the JavaScript attached to the Label and the child `DIV`), let me know.

Comment: @Jimi He's not asking how to interact with the DOM.

Comment: @rshepp The DOM is totally unrelated here. Dynamic generation of content (client side). is

Comment: @Jimi From your previous comment, it sounds like you're confused about the question (activating tabs with cookies?). And as my postman screenshot proves, the profile html is absolutely not generated client side.

Comment: @rshepp  *I don't see anything in source that would lead me to isolate the data from `div id="words`*. Doesn't seem that *confusing* to me. The HTML that contains the data the OP, apparently, is after, is not in the page until after a script generates it. Seen a thousands times.

Comment: @Jimi I think we have to agree to disagree. I understand what you are saying but the div#words thing is almost an entirely separate issue, because without sending that valid request header you literally only get one line of text returned from the server. We are both focusing on different things that are both relevant to the question.

Comment: @rshepp  I don't deny your good intentions. But, what's the point of reaching a Html Page (a task that is quite easy to complete), when it does not contain what is sought after? If there's an API that can return a JSON, then OK, but it wasn't in the question and *Web Scraping* (title of the question) has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Jimi The question says this in the 2nd paragraph: `The Duolingo website is not offering up any sort of API`. Since such API does in fact exist, it is definitely a potential answer to OP's question - scraping is an XY problem since API exists.

Comment: @rshepp Well, not an XY problem, just misinformation; anyway, if there an API that works in a way that meets the expectations, that's a whole different story. Btw, did you open the chat or was a moderator?

Comment: @Jimi it was a fat-finger moment ;)

Comment: @rshepp All right then. See whether you can close this question with something that works. I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can access dualingo profile data in JSON format via `https://www.duolingo.com/users/<username>`

eg. https://www.duolingo.com/users/Podus

This should be much easier than trying to scrape the duome profile page manually.

Comment: Interesting, but not sure it's going to work.  Ex: https://www.duome.eu/addohm/progress/ shows the chinese character `七` has been learned, but a search for that character (or 19971, or 4E03) in the JSON turns up nothing.  :(  How'd you find that?

Comment: Just tried to search for `七` in my web browser at https://www.dualingo.com/users/addohm and it found 5 results - I'm not familiar with the dualingo's profile JSON format though so I'm not sure if any of those results are useful...

Comment: Not sure why it's not turning up for me.  Thanks though, I'll play around with it and get back to you.

Comment: Still doesn't turn up for me at all.  Very weird.  Oh well.  Might still be useful to work off of this profile until I get more information from the developers.  Might be related to Chrome or something because I can see the characters when I parse the JSON information in python.